# Oracle SQL: How to replace within all members of a list

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

Using Oracle SQL...

I'd like to use the `replace` function on all values of a hardcoded list. Something like this...

```
WHERE (
    (field IN replace(('PREFIX-ITEM0','PREFIX-ITEM1','PREFIX-ITEM2','PREFIX-ITEM3','PREFIX-ITEM4','PREFIX-ITEM5','PREFIX-ITEM6','PREFIX-ITEM7','PREFIX-ITEM8','PREFIX-ITEM9'),'PREFIX-','NEWBIE-'))
)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: save the values in an table and use `IN (SELECT (Replace ....` but as you know alreasy the text you want why have it replaced in the first place?

Comment: Your code is syntactically invalid and will give `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c68f7338d80a14b1f618fc610e8fa97b)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed list of values - so they aren't coming from a table - then it would be much simpler to modify them externally before putting them into a query.

But if for some reason you can't do that, you could treat the list as a varray of strings, and use a function to replace them individually. In recent versions of Oracle you can do that with a local function defined in a `with` clause:

```
with
  function myfunc (p_in_list sys.odcivarchar2list, p_old varchar2, p_new varchar2)
  return sys.odcivarchar2list is
    l_out_list sys.odcivarchar2list;
  begin
    l_out_list := new sys.odcivarchar2list();
    l_out_list.extend(p_in_list.count);

    for i in p_in_list.first..p_in_list.last loop
      l_out_list(i) := replace(p_in_list(i), p_old, p_new);
    end loop;

    return l_out_list;
  end;
select field
from t
where field in (
    select * from myfunc(
      sys.odcivarchar2list('PREFIX-ITEM0','PREFIX-ITEM1','PREFIX-ITEM2','PREFIX-ITEM3','PREFIX-ITEM4','PREFIX-ITEM5','PREFIX-ITEM6','PREFIX-ITEM7','PREFIX-ITEM8','PREFIX-ITEM9'),
      'PREFIX-',
      'NEWBIE-')
  )
/
```

which with some dummy data with a mix of PREFIX and NEWBIE values produces:

```
FIELD
------------
NEWBIE-ITEM2
NEWBIE-ITEM3
NEWBIE-ITEM4
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=13ec8829046b6b15d6f70af6da58f3cd)